# Are there online sources containing example sentences in classical Chinese with grammar annotations?

Tags: translation, grammar, learning, classical-chinese

I came across a site that is called [zdic](http://www.zdic.net/) and holds explanation of characters, but unfortunately no example sentences like [nciku](http://www.nciku.com/) for modern Chinese.

Do you know of any source that contains sample sentences in classical Chinese with annotation about the grammar, if possible in English.

Or maybe a book that fulfils this requirement.

Comment: Why has this been down-voted so heavily?

Answer (score 2):

I guess that are the senior or junior students' Chinese textbooks **for Teachers**. You know, Chinese textbooks contains two versions, **for students and for teachers**, in which the Teachers' book contains the grammar explaination you need.

Answer (score 1):

Surely there are plenty of these kinds of books in Chinese.

Here's a link to several English textbooks
https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-of-the-best-resources-for-learning-classical-Chinese

There are also several online resources... I could make a list but you would probably find a better one by using a search engine.

zdic.net does have example sentences but as you noted, there is no English gloss.